# How to get Starlette Python agent to send logs to elastic APM server from a service running on AWS lamba?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, elastic-stack, apm, starlette

I have a Python program which uses the Starlette framework to send logs to an elastic APM server which is already running. When I test this program from my localhost, it logs transactions in elastic APM. When I run it from an AWS lambda, I do not see anything being logged into the APM server.

How can I get the service metrics to appear in elastic APM? Do I need to use Django or a different framework or is there a way to add support for lambda while using Starlette?